# rewrite rule of htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mediawiki

my url is like
 [http://www.wikibusiness.org/Professional:Abby-Jo_Tague_Mobile_Alabama_1779052](http://www.wikibusiness.org/Professional%3aAbby-Jo_Tague_Mobile_Alabama_1779052) ,
[http://www.wikibusiness.org/Professional:Abby-Sue_Elder_Canada_1728544](http://www.wikibusiness.org/Professional%3aAbby-Sue_Elder_Canada_1728544)

.I want to remove digit after last underscore using htaccess.please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root `.htaccess`:

```
RedirectMatch 301  ^/(.+?)_[0-9]+$ /$1
```

Comment: thank you. This is working but the page is not open.if you have any suggession please give.

Comment: That is due to your web server's handling of pages without `_number`. If you directly enter `http://www.wikibusiness.org/Professional%3aAbby-Sue_Elder_Canada` then also page doesn't load.